# What are the rules of catchable Exceptions in try catch blocks in Java?

Tags: java, exception

I was reading the Java Language Specification, and [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2.3) part caught my attention:

> It is a compile-time error if a catch clause can catch checked
> exception class E1 and it is not the case that the try block
> corresponding to the catch clause can throw a checked exception class
> that is a subclass or **superclass of E1,** unless E1 is Exception or a
> superclass of Exception.

The part I do not understand is **emphasized in bold** above.

Given the following hierarchy

```
class A extends Exception {}
class B extends A {}
class C extends B {}
```

Here is what I understand from:

> the try block corresponding to the catch clause can throw a checked exception class that is a subclass of E1

```
void f() {
    try {
        throw new C();
    } catch (B b) {

    }
}
```

which compiles fine..

But what is meant by

> the try block corresponding to the catch clause can throw a checked
> exception class that is a superclass of E1

?

This is what I understand, which does not compile (I wasn't expecting it to, but the JLS makes me think it would)

```
void f() {
    try {
        throw new A();
    } catch (B b) {  // will not compile

    }
}
```

Since it is highly unlikely that the specification is wrong, can you help me understand what is meant by the part I am confused with, preferably with an example that demonstrates?

Comment: It is saying that it is a compilation error if it is not the case. It is not saying that it isn't a compilation error if it is the case, suggesting that there are instances where it does compile, this not being one of those instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the easy way to understand this is with a concrete example:

```
public void doOpen(File file) throws IOException {
    new FileInputStream(file);
}
```

Note that the method is *declared* as throwing `IOException` rather than its subclass `FileNotFoundException`.

Now let us try to catch the exception that we know will be thrown when a file does not exist:

```
try {
    doOpen(someFile);
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    // print a message
}
```

The JLS says:

> It is a compile-time error if a catch clause can catch checked exception class `E1` and it is not the case that the try block corresponding to the catch clause can throw a checked exception class that is a subclass **or superclass of `E1`**, unless `E1` is `Exception` or a superclass of `Exception`.

In the catch clause in our example code, the `E1` in the JLS is `FileNotFoundException`.  The  method is declared as throwing `IOException`.  If the highlighted clause were not there (i.e. "or superclass of `E1`") then that catch would not be legal.  But it clearly *should* be legal, since the `doOpen` method *clearly could* throw `FileNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 2):

It is very tricky indeed. To understand this, you should go back to the concept of inheritance in Object Oriented Paradigm:

- If I want to create an ArrayList, I could do this in two different ways:

  1. The first one is ignoring all the inheritance concept and hardcoding the ArrayList and setting its type as ArrayList itself:

     ```java
     ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
     ```
  2. The second one is following the concept of inheritance, and we try to instance it following a higher level class/interface:

     ```java
     List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
     ```

This second approach is better for many reasons that I will not mention because its not in the scope of the answer, but since ArrayList inherits from List, we can instantiate a new ArrayList as a List object, but it is impossible to do something like this because `List` does not extend or inherits from `ArrayList`:

```java
ArrayList<String> list = new List<String>();
```

The same idea applies to Java's Catchable Exceptions. Following your example, if I have:

```java
class A extends Exception {}
class B extends A {}
class C extends B {}
```

When I'm trying to catch an exception, I want to try the lower level class (`C`) (i.e. more specific) first, because I have a greater certainty of what it means:

```java
try {
    // something here that throws C
} catch (C exc) {
    // Great! Its C! I know exactly what should I do!
} catch (B exc) {
    // Not that great, it might not be that hard to figure out what caused this
} catch (A exc) {
    // I still have some idea of what might have thrown this exception
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Oh boy, its not an exception that I mapped before... It might be harder than I thought... :(
}
```

But we have to follow the same line of thought from `ArrayList` not being able to receive a `List` object in Exceptions:

- a C exception can be caught by `catch (C exc)`, `catch (B exc)`, `catch (A exc)` and `catch (Exception e)`
- a B exception can be caught by `catch (B exc)`, `catch (A exc)` and `catch (Exception e)`
- an A exception can be caught by `catch (A exc)` and `catch (Exception e)`
- and so on...

Since A is from a "higher level" than B, it cannot be caught by `catch (B exc)`. This is why it does not compile in your example:

```java
void f() {
    try {
        throw new A();
    } catch (B b) {  // will not compile

    }
}
```

Inside the specification in the [page you linked](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2.3) there is a code snippet right before 11.3 that exemplifies what you asked, because as I already explained, you understood it right:

> It is a compile-time error if a catch clause can catch checked exception class E1 and it is not the case that the try block corresponding to the catch clause can throw a checked exception class that is a subclass or superclass of E1, unless E1 is Exception or a superclass of Exception.

This means that you cannot catch a subclass of the previous catch block, and java compilers will see it as an error. For example, if you try to do this

```java
try {
    throw new C();
} catch (A exc) {
    // do something here, because the exception will be caught
} catch (B exc) {
    // since the exception has been caught before and B is subclass of A,
    // this causes the compilation error that JLS was talking about:
    // you cannot catch a subclass of a class previously caught.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer but I am not sure if the part I am asking about has anything to do with multiple catch blocks. I might be wrong though, which is very usual.

Comment: yes it does. this is what the sub and superclass is about. It is allowed to have such a construct of catch clauses with subclases involved. Think of a method that throws an exception but can also throw subclasses.

Comment: @KorayTugay in other words, in the case that you have another catch clause that is E1 or above, then you can also have a catch clause before it that only catches a subclass of E1.

Comment: the important thing i guess is: this rule only forbids some catch clauses - it only restricts. Other rules impose more restrictions. So not everything that isn't covered by this rule is allowed. Other rules may still disallow it and leed to an error.

Answer (score 0):

note a checked exception means any exception class not extending Error or RuntimeException. It is simply saying that if you declare in the catch a checked exception other than Exception or throwable, the compiler will complain if the Exception can never be thrown by the try block.

I believe the super class of E1 may be referring to the case where an instance of E1 or a subclass of E1 may be stored as a super-class of E1. In this case the compiler may run further checks outside the logic stated to ensure that the E1 super class instance is not in fact E1 or a subclass of E1 before it complains.

If we are talking about the language specification, the actual output of the compiler may vary for the further checks part provided the output is the same for the situation specifically stated. One compiler may actually check if an E1 instance can be thrown as a super-class while another may simply show a compilation error, provided each implementation otherwise adheres to the spec.